# OpenGL how to get offset of array element in shared layout uniform block?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a `shared` layout uniform block in shader:

```
layout(shared) uniform TestBlock
{
    int test[5];
};
```

How to get offset of `test[3]`?
When I try to use `glGetUniformIndices` to get index of `test[3]`, it will return the same number of `test[0]`'s index.
So I cannot use `glGetActiveUniformsiv` to get offset of index of `test[3]`.
Then, how to get offset of `test[3]`?
(Note that I don't want to use layout `std140`.)

Comment: Read about [Program Introspection](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Program_Introspection)

Comment: "*Note that I don't want to use layout `std140`.*" You really should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays of basic types like `int`s are treated as a single value. You can't get the offset of an individual element in the array. You can however query the array stride, the number of bytes from one element in the array to the next. Then you can just do the multiplication.

Using the new program introspection API:

```
auto ix = glGetProgramResourceIndex(prog, GL_UNIFORM, "test");
GLenum props[] = {GL_ARRAY_STRIDE, GL_OFFSET};
GLint values[2] = {};
glGetProgramResourceiv(prog, GL_UNIFORM, ix, 2, &props, 2, NULL, &values);

auto byteOffset = values[1] + (3 * values[0]);
```

Comment: Small typo here : `glGetProgramResourceiv(prog, GL_UNIFORM, ix, 2, props, 2, NULL, values)`

Comment: Using the name "TestBlock.test" did not work for me. "test" worked.